# Cypher creating n number of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm wanting to create an n number of nodes, say 100, the name should start at 1 and end at 100.
Essentially looping as in below.

```
CREATE (n:GridCell{name: 1})
CREATE (n:GridCell{name: 2})
CREATE (n:GridCell{name: 3})
CREATE (n:GridCell{name: ...})
```

How do I do this in cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
UNWIND range(0, 100) AS id
CREATE (n:GridCell {name: id})
```

Documentation:

- [range()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-range)
- [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/)